# two if binding in knockout js not showing div

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two if bindings for showing a div in the HTML page for logged in and not logged in user, so they will have different information.

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="if: loggedIn() != 'true'">

<div class="col-md-9" data-bind="ifnot: loggedIn() != 'true'">
```

SO i wanted the logged in user to have a different column and different text then a logged in user.But after i used this databind it does not show anything. 
I tried `data-bind="visible"` as well. Same issue.
The loggedIn() is a string by the way.

Comment: Can you show your viewmodel as well? Also a true representation of your view - I assume you don't really have the `<div>`s nested as shown here? Is `loggedIn` an actual boolean or a string representation?

Comment: string @JamesThorpe

Answer (score 0):

Because you put the second div inside the first one so, whenever the first div condition is true its content will be shown up but in that case your inner div has its own if which does not show.You need to take out your second div outside or struct it in a way that they wouldn't overlap each other.

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/45/

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="if: loggedIn() != 'true'">
  Hello I am not logged in
</div>

<div class="col-md-9" data-bind="ifnot: loggedIn() != 'true'">
  Hi I am logged in 
</div>

<div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click:toggle" value="toggle">
</div>

 function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
   self.loggedIn = ko.observable('true');

   self.toggle = function (){
     if(self.loggedIn() == 'true'){
     self.loggedIn('false');
     }else{
     self.loggedIn('true');
     }
   }
  }  
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Got any idea how I can not make it over lap each other?

Comment: I know it's obvious but:
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="if: loggedIn() != 'true'">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9" data-bind="ifnot: loggedIn() != 'true'">
</div>

Comment: @Kadaj yea, but then i have to copy whatever is inside it , twice!

Comment: Well you probably wouldn't put a lot of code in there? I mean It's not that much of code if you are only showing/hiding one column.
Also, try to never chain if statements. It would be easier if you put some more code here.

Comment: @Maat.kaaj I got what you mean, but I want to change the class-col-md-12 and col-md-9 for logged in user and different for logged out

Comment: Why dont you use css binding then?

Comment: @Kadaj i am not sure how to use it

Comment: @Matt.kaaj will CSS binding help?

Comment: @Farhana you don't need css binding here since they are separate entity which will show. Look at update example